# Frontpad api java

Tags: java, android

Я слышал, что у frontpad есть api. Мне нужно через Java подключиться к frontpad и отправлять с мобильного приложения заказы. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вот документация, здесь должно быть все что тебе нужно
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gs81CYvJ6FD9KOseL3GOcrcR2YnEvjQqJn9mJRRc5Yk/edit#